Gravitational time dilation near the Earth
I recently read the statement that near the Earth, in the Newtonian weak gravitational field, gravity is 99.9999% mainly due to "curvature of time" (ie gravitational time dilation), and only about 0.0001% due to the warping of space. Unfortunately there was no derivation of these values. I'd be interested how you calculate these percentages. What would be the (small) gravitational redshift derived from these data?

Where did you read this statement? I’m curious as to the source.

What do you mean by "warping of space"? Spacetime curves as a whole. The curvature cannot in general be separated. Also note that since the Ricci tensor is zero in vacuum, the curvatures are equal and opposite such that the volume does not change.

The statement is actually that the largest component of the contribution to the illusion of gravitational acceleration is, in some senses obviously, the time component. It is usually done as a homework problem by asking you to compute the geodesic deviation. It is a real result, but it is a very specific way of looking at it, and not within the standard curriculum treatment of the topic.

This might help - Why can't I do this to get infinite energy?

I read this text in the Quora Blog. -  I will now reformulate the question more clearly awaiting a mathematical calculation: In the Newtonian weak gravitational field near the surface of the Earth, gravity is 99.9999% mainly due to the gravitational time dilation, and only about 0.0001% due to the curvature of space.  I'd be interested how these percentages are calculated. What is the value of the gravitational redshift?

@ReneKail Quora is by no means a reliable source of physics knowledge.

this is relevant ,showing the complexity https://www.astronomy.ohio-state.edu/pogge.1/Ast162/Unit5/gps.html

I think that the question is equivalent to 'how much does GR modify the Newtonian gravity close to Earth?' Because using the machinery of differential geometry to Newton gravity, only $\Gamma^i_{00}\neq 0$. The Ricci tensor has only the term $R_{00}\neq0$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Cartan_theory
